# squarespace version 7.1 code injection is not workig

Tags: javascript, squarespace

everybody
I injected javascript code in Sqaurespace ..settings/advanced/code injection/header

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  document.onload = displayTotalkit;
  function displayTotalkit(){
       console.log("here log message!");
}
</scirpt>
```

this is simple javascript code, but it's not working at all.
I tried to solve this problem for 3 days.
Somebody said to me  but I know Ajax loading is disabled in version 7.1.
I have to finish my work in today.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo error.`</scirpt>`
2. Please use `window.onload` instead of `document.onload`
3. If you put code inside the script tag, please don't use src attribute.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = displayTotalkit;
    function displayTotalkit(){
      console.log("no src here log message!");
    }
</script>
```

[w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html) says:

> The script may be defined within the contents of the SCRIPT element or in an external file. If the src attribute is not set, user agents must interpret the contents of the element as the script. ***If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI***. Note that the charset attribute refers to the character encoding of the script designated by the src attribute; it does not concern the content of the SCRIPT element.

Comment: Thank you , sir.
The code i had written has some typo errors, but  my real code didn't have any typo errors.
And it's not still working. I think it's the problem connected with setting.